# Why are the two sphere capacitors are said to be in parallel

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

When two metal spheres at a large distance are connected to each other by a thin conducting wire why are the two sphere capacitors are said to be in parallel and not in series?

Comment: When two spherical capacitance are in connected with each other through negligible resistance wire,then both of capacitor having capacity to hold charge for whole connected body got added.potential may constant for bodies.we Know potential same meant to capacitor are in parallel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an isolated sphere the other plate is taken as infinity.
So you now have the two spheres at the same potential because they are connected with a conducting wire and their other plates (infinity) are at the same potential.
This can be thought of as a parallel arrangement as circuit elements in parallel have the same potential difference across them.